# Меню в элементе listview

Tags: android

Доброго времени суток, есть ли стандартный способ для добавления меню элементу listview как в клиенте контакта ?
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`PopupMenu`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupMenu.html). В `support library` так же есть [версия](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/PopupMenu.html.) для API < 11. Его удобство в данном случае очевидно — он поддерживает `MenuInflater`.

Answer (score 3):

Да, можно

например класс [ListPopupWindow](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListPopupWindow.html)

или более абстрактный [PopupWindow](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupWindow.html)